# Use Ubuntu as Active Directory server? (Windows users login-security)

Tags: server, directory

We are a very small business (5 people) and all of us use Windows 7 on the desktop.
I'm planning to run an Ubuntu box to share Internet connection and use a proxy.
I'd like also to expand this box to use it as an Active Directory server so users can, when they login on their workstations, get authenticated by the Ubuntu box. Is this possible?

Comment: I'll try the following solution right now! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FedoraDirectoryServer Ubuntu 389 Directory Server! Included in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04! :-D Who needs Samba4 ? :-P

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is doable.

I am just setting up a Ubuntu machine to act as an Active Directory equivalent.

I have read that Samba 4 is designed specifically for this purpose.

It is still in development (alpha version) but it is supposed to be relatively stable.

http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO

There are also other flavours of linux projects set up specifically to address the active directory need.

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/579308-weekend-project-replace-active-directory-with-resara-server-and-samba4.

What I am expecting is to have my XP and Win 7 machines able to use my Ubuntu server as an active directory equivalent when logging into the "domain".

Answer (score 0):

MS Active Directory can not be installed on Ubuntu (or any other OS apart from Windows Server family OS's). You can use other LDAP implementations for the same purpose though.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can connect to a Windows Server running AD using Ubuntu, but not the other way around. Not sure if you can configure an AD server wich is a Microsoft product in an Ubuntu box.

You can read this link to see if it helps you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=280702

Comment: Thanks!I have read somewhere that I can use samba as a basic Directory service in terms of allowing users to log-in on the network; any tought on that?

Comment: You mean using Samba to connect to a Windows AD server?

Comment: -1 that link is from 2006.

Comment: Even if it is old doesn't mean it doesn't apply. There's some good info there regarding the version of Ubuntu people are running

Comment: Sure, it has some useful information, but it's cluttered with a bunch of things that need to be updated.